# test_forms with django give AssertionError

Tags: python, django, forms, sqlite, testing

I am trying to write test for my forms with my Django project.
I try to test the following BookForm:
forms.py

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'summary', 'tag', 'genre', 'language', 'book_format', 'read_date']
    #labels = 
    widgets = {
        'author': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
            forms.Select,
            reverse_lazy('author_form'),),
        'tag': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
            forms.SelectMultiple,
            reverse_lazy('author_form'),),            

    }       
    permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    # print(self.request.user)
    super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My test_forms.py looks like that:

```
class BookFormTest(TestCase):

def test_read_date_in_the_past(self):
    print('BookForm TEST Lounched')
    title = 'TestBookPast'
    author = 'TestAuthorPast'
    date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    form_data = {'title': title, 'author': author, 'read_date': date}
    form = BookForm(data=form_data)        
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

I have no idea why it is not working. Maybe I forgot about something really important?

I always get this AssertionError:

> self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
>   AssertionError: False is not true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the form is not valid with the data you provided. It might be because you are passing a `date` object as `read_date` and not a string containing a date.

Inspect `form.errors` to get a definite answer why the form is invalid.

To do that, you can add a print statement just before the assertion.

```
print(form.errors)
```

If the output is swallowed by your test framework and not printed to the console, you can also try the debugger. Add this line:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

The test will then stop at that line with the prompt `(pdb)`. Enter `p form.errors` to print the errors.

Then you can enter `q` to exit the debugger.

Alternatively, you can also start a Python shell with `python manage.py shell` and enter your code manually.

Comment: Thank you very much. First part helps with form.errors. 
There was error with choice author from list, I should create test_author then pass that to form_data ={'author': test_author.id} that author can be a choosen from drop list.